# How to match overlapping keywords with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This example finds only `sam`. How to make it find **both** `sam` and `samwise`?

```
var regex = /sam|samwise|merry|pippin/g;
var string = 'samwise gamgee';
var match = string.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```

Note: this is simple example, but my real regexes are created by joining 500 keywords at time, so it's too cumbersome to search all overlapping and make *a special case* for them with something like `/sam(wise)/`. The other obvious solution I can think of, is to just iterate though all keywords individually, but I think it must be a fast and *elegant*, single-regex solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "find"? I.e. how are you going to use the results?

Comment: I want `['sam', 'samwise']` as a result

Answer (score 2):

You can use lookahead regex with capturing group for this overlapping match:

```
var regex = /(?=(sam))(?=(samwise))/;
var string = 'samwise';
var match = string.match( regex ).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["sam", "samwise"]
```

- It is important to not to use `g` (global) flag in the regex.
- `filter(Boolean)` is used to remove first empty result from matched array.

Comment: This works for the case I've wrote first, but unfortunately it returns `null` if string is `sam`. Moreover, if I add `(?=(merry))` to the regex it returns `null` to *every* possible string.

Comment: This requires that all keywords match simultaneously at the same offset, i.e. all keywords must be prefixes of each other.

Comment: @AlexanderVasenin: For `samwise gamgee` input you still want to match `samwise` and `sam` only?

Comment: String could be anything, if it's `merry and samwise are friends` I want it to match ["sam", "samwise", "merry"].

Comment: In that `(?=.*?(merry))(?=.*?(sam))(?=.*?(samwise))` will work for you

Comment: Sorry, but this version doesn't work with `merry` input. Turns out this a really hard case for a regex. I feel myself like a Truman hitting a boat against the world wall.

Comment: Hmm JS regex doesn't have fancy flavors of PCRE. I guess you will need to iterate the loop and check each keyword in input text.

Comment: @anubhava Ironically the first book I've consulted was iconic [Programming Perl](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Perl-Unmatched-processing-scripting-ebook/dp/B007S291SA/) and I haven't found answer there

Answer (score 1):

Why not just [map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff679976%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) [indexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/53xtt423%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) on array substr:

```
var string = 'samwise gamgee';
var substr = ['sam', 'samwise', 'merry', 'pippin'];

var matches = substr.map(function(m) {
  return (string.indexOf(m) < 0 ? false : m);
}).filter(Boolean);
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k89gdw6y/2/) `console.log(matches);`

> Array [ "sam", "samwise" ]

Probably of better performance than using regex. But if you need the regex functionality e.g. for caseless matching, word boundaries, returned matches... use with [exec method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z908hy33%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
var matches = substr.map(function(v) {
  var re = new RegExp("\\b" + v, "i"); var m = re.exec(string); 
  return (m !== null ? m[0] : false);
}).filter(Boolean);
```

[This one](https://jsfiddle.net/s0qsqx3c/5/) with `i`-flag (*ignore case*) returns each first match with initial `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a simple and elegant solution, but I've got something that uses a single regex:

```
function quotemeta(s) {
    return s.replace(/\W/g, '\\$&');
}

let keywords = ['samwise', 'sam'];

let subsumed_by = {};
keywords.sort();
for (let i = keywords.length; i--; ) {
    let k = keywords[i];
    for (let j = i - 1; j >= 0 && k.startsWith(keywords[j]); j--) {
        (subsumed_by[k] = subsumed_by[k] || []).push(keywords[j]);
    }
}

keywords.sort(function (a, b) b.length - a.length);
let re = new RegExp('(?=(' + keywords.map(quotemeta).join('|') + '))[\\s\\S]', 'g');

let string = 'samwise samgee';

let result = [];
let m;
while (m = re.exec(string)) {
    result.push(m[1]);
    result.push.apply(result, subsumed_by[m[1]] || []);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var re = /((sam)(?:wise)?)/;
var m = 'samwise'.match(re); // gives ["samwise", "samwise", "sam"]
var m = 'sam'.match(re);     // gives ["sam", "sam", "sam"]
```

You can use [Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960473) to remove dupplicates.

Comment: Sorry, you just trying to implement a special case for overlapping keywords. The idea is to handle them all equally, overlapping or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create special cases, and if order doesn't matter, why not first match only full names with:

```
\b(sam|samwise|merry|pippin)\b
```

and then, filter if some of these doesn't contain shorter one? for example with:

```
(sam|samwise|merry|pippin)(?=\w+\b)
```

It is not one elegant regex, but I suppose it is simpler than iterating through all matches.