# How to match overlapping substrings as whole words (with multiple occurence) with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31489509/4970211) but it doesn't work when there are multiple occurrences of the same word.

I want to count the occurrence of both `site` and `site web` in the string `"site web site"`.

I tried with the following code :

```js
var regex = /(?:\b)((?=(site))(?=(site web)))(?:\b)/;
var string = 'site web site';
var match = string.match( regex ).filter(Boolean);

console.log(match)
```

This code returns `["site", "site web"]` but I want it to return `["site", "site", "site web"]` since `site` appears two times in the string.

> **Note :** In my case, I have hundreds of words to match.

More, if the input is `site webS site`, the expected output is `["site", "site"]`. The input is supposed to be a complete text with punctuations to take into account (`.,?!/;`...).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e8o6b9vm/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, but I don't want to alter my list of keywords since I'll probably have to match hundreds of keywords in a text of thousands of words.

Comment: Not a problem, use `site|web site` regex, see https://jsfiddle.net/y49kq78v/

Comment: It's working but when I try with, let's say `site webS site`, it's still returning the same array `["site", "site web", "site"]` when it's not supposed to. It should return `["site", "site"]`.

Comment: Ok, that is a better use case. Reopened.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find if the words of a list of words appears in a string and you have hundred of words, you need to use a good string searching algorithm. I think for your use case the best option is Aho Corasick algorithm. It achieves near to O(n) complexity which is much faster than using regexp.

Check this link:

[Aho Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)

I used it and I can say you it works very fast.
If you decide to use it, there are available in github multiple implementations of this algorithm. You can search a good one for your programming language and use it.

I hope this helps.